# How to insert a custom object that inherits from the object Account with custom fields

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to save the fields BillingAddress, ShippingAddress and a custom field "FiscalAddress"

I understand that the API only have BillingAddress and ShippingAddress and I need one more.

I want insert in database (SOQL) but the logic of my script is wrong.

What corrections you should do to insert the input text fields in the Account table?

error console:

> `<apex:inputField>` value binding '{!a.BillingStreet}'. `<apex:inputField>` can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.

**Markup**

```
<apex:page Controller="CustomAccount" >
    <apex:form >

        <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Contact">

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.BillingStreet}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.BillingCity}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.BillingState}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.BillingPostalCode}"/>

                <apex:inputField value="{!a.ShippingStreet}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.ShippingCity}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.ShippingState}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.ShippingPostalCode}"/>


                <apex:inputField value="{!a.FiscalStreet}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.FiscalCity}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.FiscalState}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.FiscalPostalCode}"/>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Code**

```
public with sharing class CustomAccount {
    public Account a { get; set; }

    public List<Account> samepage { get; set; }

    public CustomAccount(){
       a = new Account();
    }

    public PageReference save() {
       insert a;  

    }


}
```

[image: Fiscal Address (custom fields)]

Markup new version

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
      <apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingStreet}" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingCity}" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingState}" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingPostalCode}" />

        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.ShippingStreet}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.ShippingCity}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.ShippingState}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.ShippingPostalCode}"/>


        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.FiscalStreet__c}" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.FiscalCity__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.FiscalState__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.FiscalPostalCode__c}"/>

      </apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" />
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: So you have a custom class called Account in your code somewhere?

Comment: i want use the object Account https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_account.htm with my FiscalAddress custom field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create the fields in Setup first (Setup > Customize > Accounts > Fields or Setup > Object Manager > Account > Fields & Relationships). Once you do so, you can write your page using the StandardController:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
      <apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingStreet}" />
        ... other fields ...
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.FiscalStreet__c}" />
        ... other fields ...
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" />
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Note that Custom Fields that you create end in `__c` (as demonstrated in the code). You'll want to also read about [Display Field Values with Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_display_field_values.htm).

Comment: thank you so much 
but my class "CustomAccount" 
it's correct? for query insert

Comment: @Apu There's no such thing as a "query insert" in Salesforce. DML operations and Query statements are two entirely separate concepts. As I stated, you must first create any custom fields you need, then you can reference them in your Visualforce code. In addition, if you're getting an error for a standard field, it is likely that you have another class that is overriding the standard Account object, which won't work. Start from my example to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Hi,
I added the new version of the apex page.
the page is displayed correctly but does not save the data in the database. the logic of my class CustomAccount

Comment: @Apu What error messages are you getting, if any? Try adding `<apex:pageMessages/>` somewhere in your VF page to see if you get any errors.

Comment: I had to add Account.name. 
thanks for the advice of the label <apex:pageMessages/>